# Slow JPA startup

Tags: orm, jpa, java-ee-6, jpa-2.0, glassfish-3

I created the JPA 2.0 entity classes for our whole database (~200 tables), and now each time I rebuild my application and start it for the first time I get these messages:

```
INFO: <entity_classname> actually got transformed
INFO: <entity_otherclassname> actually got transformed
...
```

And the output of these (info) messages in Glassfish is extremely slow, it now takes almost a minute (!) to start the application.

I think the messages are the problem, because sometimes the Glassfish console freezes in the Netbeans window (no messages are output) and then the whole process takes about 5 seconds.

I couldn't find a way to disable these messages, is there a way to speed things up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that this is due to dynamic weaving of your JPA classes. Could you try with [static weaving](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Introduction_to_EclipseLink_Application_Development_(ELUG)#Configuring_Static_Weaving) (or no weaving at all but this will disable things like lazy-loading)?

Comment: Or, as an alternative, try to disable weaving at all?

Comment: Based on the link above, setting *eclipselink.weaving* to *false* solved my headache (and will try static weaving as well for our daily builds - now that I know about it), so from now on only those classes are transformed that are actually used. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Gabor Note that disable weaving will disable things like lazy loading. I'd suggest to weave them for production.